# Java filter map inside List<Object>

Tags: java, list, dictionary, java-stream

I've run in to bit of a problem here and can't seem to find a solution.

I've got a list of objects that contain a Map of String, Object2.
Object 2 itself contains a Map of String, String

How do I sort this to end up with a List with Map String, Object2 only containing entries where Map String, String is not empty?

This is what I got so far:

```
 list.stream()
            .filter(i -> i.getServices().entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(c -> c.getValue() != null))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However that results in the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Map.Entry<String,Object>> to boolean
```

I've been banging my head against this all morning. If someone could help me out here I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance!

With flatmap I end up with the required lists of map but lose the superclass, like so:

```
         List<Entry<String, Service>> a = list.stream()
         .flatMap(cus -> cus.getServices().entrySet().stream())
         .filter(service -> service.getValue() != null)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Edit: for clarifications:
1st object:

```
public class Subscription {
    ...
    public Map <String, Service> services;
}
```

2nd object:

```
public class Service {

...
private Map<String, String> params;

}
```

"params" is what needs to be filtered.

Comment: You need to end your innermost stream with a call to collect

Comment: By "empty" do you mean that the map is empty (no entries, size 0) or do you mean "Map only contains values that are not mapped to null" which seems to be what you filtered for.

Comment: Yeah, the second option is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, your lambda is returning a stream, the result of the call to `filter` when you need to return a `boolean`.
I'm not certain of the types, but I think this is more or less what you want:

```
      List<Subscription> foo = list.stream()
          .map(s -> s.services.entrySet().stream()
                        .filter(x -> x.getValue() != null)
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)))
          .map(m -> new Subscription(m))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Not quite, this only filters out entries where map inside list is empty. What I'm looking for is filtering that map by value (which is an object) and it's parameter which happens to be a map of string, string.

Comment: If you want to filter the elements of the inner map, you can't filter the list itself. You need to use map on the elements of the list, and then apply the filter within the map operation.

Comment: Thank you, this is getting close but the desirable result is List<Subscription>. Map itself is sorted correct now though.

Comment: Ah, that's easy. Updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is pretty much what I was looking for!

Comment: @Gal can't you make *map(m -> new Subscription(m))* into *Subscription::new*?

Comment: @Eugene Probably, I'm too used to Scala :)